# How to disable re-sending request after it was canceled in Angular 2

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I have a http request like this.

```
let request:Observable<any> = this.http.post( someUrl, someData)
```

Now I want to cancel this request after sending.When I call request.subscribe().unsubscribe()   it cancels the request and re-sending it again. I want to prevent re-sending it after cancel.